# Declarative WebPart on publishing page

Tags: 2010, web-part, publishing-page

I have made a publishing page layout that has a WebPartZone and a MediaWebPart in the ZoneTemplate. 
Example below.

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Fokusøki Media" ID="WebPartZone1" AllowLayoutChange="true" AllowPersonalization="false">
  <ZoneTemplate>
    <PublishingWebControls:MediaWebPart ID="mediaWebPart1" AutoPlay="true" AllowEdit="true" AllowClose="true" Title="MediaWebPart" runat="server" />
  </ZoneTemplate>
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

The WebPart show just fine on the page, and works like supposed. But when i click "Save and Close" or "Publish" on the ribbon, I get the following error message.

> The operation could not be completed because the Web Part is not on
>   this page.
>   Stack Trace:

```
[WebPartPageUserException: The operation could not be completed because the Web Part is not on this page.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.ThrowIfNotOnPage(WebPart webPart) +27111847
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.GetStorageKey(WebPart webPart) +30
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.MediaWebPart.UpdateWebPartProperties() +380
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.MediaWebPart.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +49
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428
```

Comment: Is your publishing infrastructure enabled? Did you check out the page before editing?

Comment: @Mike. Yes it is enabled and yes, the page was checked out.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the web part to the page layout using  as mentioned here: [link](https://achrafsp.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/provisioning-webparts-declaratively-and-programmatically/)

Comment: Do not put just links.. Links might go down. And not all people have access to links. So try putting some important part of the answer here and keep link for reference.. Thanks